# if condition in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a AJAX request where I would like to pass data based on if condition.

`data: testobj`  is  a JSON object that will return `{"name":"tom"}`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.asp',
    data: testobj,
    success: function(response){
         alert(response);
    }
});
```

the data might sometimes be undefined or null. so i'm looking to have something like this

```
if (testobj != undefined){
    data: testobj
}
```

Is this possible to have this condition without duplicating the whole block ?

Comment: What do you do if it is undefined? `data: ` can accept `undefined` as the value, it'l skip it as if you didn't define it. No duplication or conditionals required.

Answer (score -1):

Just store your config separately.

```
const config = { type: 'POST', url: 'test.asp', success: function () {} }
if (testObj != undefined) config.data = testObj
$.ajax(config)
```